# Jenkins build not reading or recognizing all of the environment variables with a Jenkins build in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, environment-variables, jenkins, mac-mini

I have an issue reading or recognizing all of the environment variables with a Jenkins build.

All of those necessary variables have been set via Terminal and are properly written in both .bashrc and .zshrc .

My build.sh requires those environment variables to be set and when I am building manually (running build.sh via Terminal) - everything goes very smooth.

The issue I am having is when I try to build with Jenkins, it does not "read/recognize" those already set environment variables. When I start a build with the following Jenkinsfile I am not getting anything that is expected (as I would get in Terminal).

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'MacAgent-AppleSilicon_Test'
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        }

    stages {
        stage ('Jenkins') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    $SHELL
                    whoami
                    brew list
                    echo $HOME
                    echo $PATH
                    echo $NVM_DIR
                    echo $JAVA_HOME
                    echo $ANDROID_HOME
                    echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
                    echo $ANDROID_NDK_HOME
                    nvm ls
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ONLY** results I am getting are the following:

```
$SHELL => /bin/zsh
whoami => ec2-user
$PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Everything else return empty echo and for nvm ls - it fails since nvm: command not found.

Here is my .plist:

```
<key>Label</key> 
    <string>com.jenkins.ci</string> 
<key>UserName</key> 
    <string>ec2-user</string> 
<key>SessionCreate</key> 
<key>ProgramArguments</key> 
<array> 
    <string>java</string> 
    <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string> 
    <string>-jar</string> 
    <string>/Users/ec2-user/Jenkins/remoting.jar</string> 
    <string>-jnlpUrl</string> 
    <string>http://ip-of-jenkins-master/computer/mac_vm/slave-agent.jnlp</string> 
</array>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<key>StandardOutPath</key> 
<string>/Users/ec2-user/Jenkins/stdout.log</string> 
<key>StandardErrorPath</key> 
<string>/Users/ec2-user/Jenkins/error.log</string>
```

I have found a solution that works for now, I have set those Environment Variables on Jenkins - **Nodes -> Slave_Agent -> Configure -> Node properties/Environment Variables**.

This works for now but as soon as I start at least one build .bashrc and .zshrc are removed/gone from the macOS Agent.

Would really appreciate suggestions about possible solutions as to how to make Jenkins builds to read Environment Variables, without having it set under Node Properties.

=====

[Edit]: Here is my edited .plist file, with EnvironmentVariables property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.jenkins.ci</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>java</string> 
    <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string> 
    <string>-jar</string> 
    <string>/Users/ec2-user/Jenkins/remoting.jar</string> 
    <string>-jnlpUrl</string> 
    <string>http://ip-of-jenkins-master/computer/mac_vm/slave-agent.jnlp</string> 
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
   <dict>
    <key>JAVA_HOME</key>
    <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is adding environment variables to `/etc/profile` and then sourcing that file.

```
sh '''
  source /etc/profile
  chmod +x ./build.sh
  ./build.sh
'''
```

Couldn't figure out why sourcing .bashrc and .zshrc didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem may be because macOS Agents don't run as a shell script, so .bashrc and .zshrc aren't being run.

May be you need to add an `EnvironmentVariables` property your .plist? I found this in `man launchd.plist`;

```
     EnvironmentVariables <dictionary of strings>
     This optional key is used to specify additional environmental variables to
     be set before running the job. Each key in the dictionary is the name of an
     environment variable, with the corresponding value being a string
     representing the desired value.  NOTE: Values other than strings will be
     ignored.
```

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I have added EnvironmentVariables property but so far it didn't help. Maybe I am missing something? Please check my edit in the initial post for my edited .plist file.